# 20VDC LED Illumination

Tags: led, schematics, test-equipment

I'm looking to build a simple test circuit, where I can get an LED to illuminate when it senses 20VDC or above, and to remain off if it is sensing any less.

Comment: How sharp a turn-on do you need, and what is the maximum voltage you expect? And how much current will you allow your monitor to draw?

Comment: The sharpness of the LED doesn't matter, just looking for a positive indication.  The maximum voltage that might be seen is 28VDC.  As for the monitor draw, I won't be drawing any amperage. It will literally just be an LED bulb, either illuminating or not.

Comment: A comparator would work.  Divide down the input with a resistor divider so it is in the range of the comparator.

Comment: 20 volt zener, and op-amp connected as a comparator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f99Q91.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The LED turns on fairly sharply at about 20 volts, and the circuit draws about 10 mA at 20 volts and about 20 mA at 28 volts.

Comment: Great schematic, just what I was looking for. This is what I'll build, thanks.